# Questions about developing spring-cloud-sdk,converging all develop dependencies

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-consul

I developed a sdk that integrates the consul and actuator dependencies of the microservices, but there is a problem. If the actuator dependency exists, it always reports an error, the consul injection configuration fails. and the actuator is removed it will be ok.

some code :

https://github.com/lixinglin213/spring-cloud-sdk

Comment: please provide the error and the spring cloud and spring boot versions

Comment: @spencergibb Thanks for your response, spring-boot version is 2.1.8.RELEASE,spring-cloud version is Greenwich.SR3.
the error is :
com.ecwid.consul.transport.TransportException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8500 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Comment: The reason is that my configuration does not take effect，

the application.yml:

```yaml
msp:
  registry:
    host: 172.16.34.156
    port: 9090
    tags:
      - demo=buhao
    prefer-ip-address: true
    instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.cloud.client.ip-address}:${server.port}
  monitor:
    actuator:
      include: "*"
      show-details: always
```

Comment: Those values need to go in bootstrap.yml

Comment: There is another way to override the ConsulClient bean. This initialization sequence guarantees the latest configuration.

code:
https://github.com/lixinglin213/spring-cloud-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/com/thunisoft/msp/sdk/config/registry/RegistryConfigure.java